# How can I get openRTSP working on windows

Tags: rtsp

I would like to stream an RTSP stream to my machine in windows 10.

How can I get openRTSP working on windows?

http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/

Have you tried it, and did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can find here git 
https://github.com/ZhaoliangGuo/live555-simple-demo-4-windows
Compile with vs2010, pay attention that in file playCommon.cpp ip are hardcoded.
Also windows signals not implemented i.e. on closing exe, it will not send TEARDOWN to server.

Answer (score -1):

openRTSP - A command line program. Hence, We can execute by the openRTSP application using a terminal application like git-bash in windows.

syntax to execute the application:
Usage: D:\PATH\TO\openRTSP.exe [-p ] [-r|-q|-4|-i] [-a|-v] [-V] [-d ] [-D  [-c] [-S ] [-n] [-O] [-t|-T ] [-u  ] [-s ]|[-U ] [-E ] [-z ] [-g user-agent] [-k  ] [-P ] [-K] [-w  -h ] [-f ] [-y] [-H] [-Q []] [-F ] [-b ] [-B ] [-I ] [-m] [|-R []] (or D:\live555\live\testProgs\openRTSP.exe -o [-V] )

Eg: Suppose, If we need to stream the IP camera through this application, then use the following command ./openRTSP rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.1:554/sample/media

note: "admin" is the username and passwords for some IP cameras.

syntax: rtsp://< ipaddress : port >/sample/media